# How i can convert that CMD script in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have that CMD script

```
"C:\Program Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI-3.10.1\bin\testrunner.bat" "-shttps://localhost:44330 Test Suite" -r -a -j -f${WORKSPACE} "-RJUnit-Style HTML Report" -FXML "-EDefault environment" "C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\REST-Project-1-readyapi-project.xml"
```

How i can convert in PowerShell sript?

i tried that

```
 Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI-3.10.1\bin\testrunner.bat' -ArgumentList '-shttps://localhost:44330 Test Suite', '-r','-a', '-j', '${WORKSPACE}','-RJUnit-Style HTML Report', '-FXML','-EDefault environment', 'C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\REST-Project-1-readyapi-project.xml'
```

Comment: If you insist to run the BAT file, you should start "cmd /c C:\path\To\Your\testrunner.bat". But this doesn't convert the CMD script to a PowerShell script. For this purpose you will have to understand each line in the BAT file and use an appropriate PS command instead.

Comment: I cannot help but wonder if there is more to this question than is presented. What is the reason for converting the `cmd` script into a `powershell` script?